# Not able to access nested objects inside a JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, nested-object

I am trying to extract nested objects inside a JSON file. The JSON file contains information about Indian **states** and **districts** and looks something like this:-
https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json

```
{
"Haryana": {
    "districtData": {

      "Ambala": {
        "notes": "",
        "active": 2,
        "confirmed": 14,
        "deceased": 1,
        "recovered": 11,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      "Bhiwani": {
        "notes": "",
        "active": 1,
        "confirmed": 3,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 2,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      "Charkhi Dadri": {
        "notes": "",
        "active": 0,
        "confirmed": 1,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 1,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      "Faridabad": {
        "notes": "",
        "active": 18,
        "confirmed": 61,
        "deceased": 1,
        "recovered": 42,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      "Fatehabad": {
        "notes": "",
        "active": 0,
        "confirmed": 1,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 1,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      "Gurugram": {
        "notes": "",
        "active": 19,
        "confirmed": 57,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 38,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      }
    }

"Maharashtra": {
    "districtData": {
      "Other States": {
        "notes": "Cases from other States/UTs",
        "active": 24,
        "confirmed": 27,
        "deceased": 3,
        "recovered": 0,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      "Ahmednagar": {
        "notes": "",
        "active": 17,
        "confirmed": 42,
        "deceased": 2,
        "recovered": 23,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      "Akola": {
        "notes": "",
        "active": 30,
        "confirmed": 39,
        "deceased": 1,
        "recovered": 8,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      "Amravati": {
        "notes": "",
        "active": 17,
        "confirmed": 28,
        "deceased": 7,
        "recovered": 4,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      "Aurangabad": {
        "notes": "",
        "active": 131,
        "confirmed": 161,
        "deceased": 8,
        "recovered": 22,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      "Bhandara": {
        "notes": "",
        "active": 1,
        "confirmed": 1,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 0,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      "Beed": {
        "notes": "",
        "active": 0,
        "confirmed": 1,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 1,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      "Buldhana": {
        "notes": "Reconciled as per MH bulleting 24/04",
        "active": 1,
        "confirmed": 21,
        "deceased": 1,
        "recovered": 19,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      "Chandrapur": {
        "notes": "",
        "active": 1,
        "confirmed": 3,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 2,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      }
   }
}
```

The above information represents district data objects nested inside state objects(Here district is equivalent of a city). For example, **Haryana** is the state and **Ambala** is a district in Haryana. So there are multiple states and inside each state there are multiple districts. I want to access the **active** and **deceased** objects inside the districts and create an array of all district objects in India which contains information about all the districts which looks like this:-

```
[
  {
   "active":
   "deceased":
   "recovered":
   "districtname":"District-A"
   "statename":
  },
  {
   "active":
   "deceased":
   "recovered":
   "districtname":"District-B"
   "statename":
  },
  {
   "active":
   "deceased":
   "recovered":
   "districtname":"District-C"
   "statename":
  },
  {
   "active":
   "deceased":
   "recovered":
   "districtname":"District-D"
   "statename":
  }
]
```

I have tried the `for...in` approach and also tried to convert the inner objects into array but was not able to loop inside properly. Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Comment: Your result array has invalid syntax. You cannot have an array with key value pairs. Please correct it so that it's either an object or remove the keys.

Comment: @TheFool Corrected it

Comment: Now I got it, that was confusing XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created following example. It will create an array of objects containing the 
state name the district name the active key and the delta values.

I am using object.entries which returns an array of arrays containing the key value pair. Essentially an array of tuples. I combine this with object deconstruction and the spread operator.

```js
const transformFlat = (obj) => {
  const result = [];
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([stateName, { districtData }]) =>
    Object.entries(districtData).forEach(([districtName, { active, delta }]) =>
      result.push({
        state: stateName,
        district: districtName,
        active,
        ...delta,
      })
    )
  );
  return result;
};

console.log(transformFlat({
  Haryana: {
    districtData: {
      Ambala: {
        notes: '',
        active: 2,
        confirmed: 14,
        deceased: 1,
        recovered: 11,
        delta: {
          confirmed: 0,
          deceased: 0,
          recovered: 0,
        },
      },
      Bhiwani: {
        notes: '',
        active: 1,
        confirmed: 3,
        deceased: 0,
        recovered: 2,
        delta: {
          confirmed: 0,
          deceased: 0,
          recovered: 0,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  Maharashtra: {
    districtData: {
      'Other States': {
        notes: 'Cases from other States/UTs',
        active: 24,
        confirmed: 27,
        deceased: 3,
        recovered: 0,
        delta: {
          confirmed: 0,
          deceased: 0,
          recovered: 0,
        },
      },
      'Ahmednagar': {
        notes: '',
        active: 17,
        confirmed: 42,
        deceased: 2,
        recovered: 23,
        delta: {
          confirmed: 0,
          deceased: 0,
          recovered: 0,
        },
      },
    },
  },
}))
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your approach

Answer (score 1):

this is one way of how to loop through objects but I am not sure if it's the most efficient one.

```js
const obj = {

"a": {
    
    "b":{
        "b1":1,
        "b2":2,
    },
    "c":{
      "c1":3,
      "c2":4,
    }

  } 

}


for(let key in obj){
  let val = obj[key]
  for(let k in val){
  
    let  v = val[k]
    for (let k2 in v){
      console.log(k2, v[k2])
    }
    
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `for` loop with `Object.values()`

```
for (let value of Object.values(obj)) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

`obj` is your data.